# Сборка проекта Qt Subdirs

Tags: qt, qmake

Имеется группа проектов Qt, среди которых основное приложение, динамическая библиотека и статическая библиотека. Требуется организовать их совместную сборку с учетом зависимостей. Делал это с помощью проекта SUBDIRS по [этой статье](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2425). Вот файл sgip_global.pro группы проектов:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

sgip_main.subdir = ../sgip
sgip_driver.subdir = ../sgip_sokol_dll/usb_sgip_dll
sgip_db.subdir = ../rzmdblib/lib_db_rzm

SUBDIRS = sgip_main sgip_driver sgip_db

sgip_main.depends = sgip_driver sgip_db
```

При этом создаётся каталог сборки проекта sgip_global, в котором появляется один makefile. Остальные проекты при этом собираются в том же каталоге, где находятся исходники. Это неправильно, ведь автор обещал, что

> Весь проект типа subdirs вместе со своими дочерними проектами билдится в один shadow каталог — с повторением структуры каталогов исходников. Очень удобно.

Как достичь такой сборки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, подпроект не может находиться в директории, отличной от той, где находится основной pro-файл. Когда я переместил все подпроекты в правильный каталог, всё заработало.